# Rally: Seeing information about the current user from a web client

Tags: rally

I'm writing a Rally app using REST service calls and JQuery. I'd like to customize app behavior to the current user, i.e., show their default project. Is there a way to get a username or ID for the current auth session? The closest I've found is this website url, which redirects to the userid (if you request it while logged in).

https://rally1.rallydev.com/#

But is there a real way to do it? A REST call would be nice, but I guess that's not RESTful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a request to https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.38/user.js and it will return results for the currently logged in user.

Include UserProfile and DefaultProject in your fetch and any other fields on Project, Workspace, WorkspaceConfiguration and UserProfile objects and you should be able to get most of the info you're looking for.

If you're using SDK 2 some of this information is already available in the current context:

```
Rally.environment.getContext().getUser();
```